# How to integrate box api with salesforce via jwt

Tags: salesforce, box

I want to integrate salesforce with box via api not the default package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question since it took a while to discover all parts and might be useful for somebody else.

1. Install https://github.com/box/box-salesforce-sdk on a sandbox as an unmanaged pack.
2. Use BoxPlatformApiConnection class to authenticate, don't try to build your own tokens in apex.
3. Use https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter if you need to quickly switch between C# generated keys (RSACryptoServiceProvider) and openssl .pem formats.